# Reinstall nvidia-prime

Tags: drivers, package-management, software-installation

A friend was trying to solve [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1220426) on his laptop and mistakenly autoremoved `nvidia-prime` before shutting down.

Now the laptop won't display anything when booting linux (which doesn't seem too weird). I believe reinstalling the package should fix it, but unfortunately I can't do it the regular way. Here are my options I think:

*Disable the video card in the Bios and work from there. Unfortunately I don't have the laptop at hand so I can't check if this is doable.

*Check if there are any "repair" boot option which would allow me to fix the issue. (Can't tell you for the moment because I don't have my hands on the laptop). I never used those tools before so I don't know what is doable and what isn't.

*Boot on a live usb key and use the package manager to install `nvidia-prime` but get it to install the package in the main installation root directory rather than on the usb key. I know this is difficult/impossible to do as well.

*Install from source. Allows to choose the target and everything, but there's no real INSTALL guide available on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/0.6.2) (no Makefile as well) so I don't really know how to go about it.

Assuming options 1 and 2 don't work, can anyone tell me which option between 3 and 4 is better/doable and how to do it precisely?

The laptop is on Kubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to boot in recovery mode, access the root CLI and from there `apt-get install nvidia-prime`. Everything worked again on the next reboot.